# Strange behavior of `hdiutil`

Tags: macos, bash

```
declare -i s=${foo}; n=${bar}; mp=${baz}; cn=${qux}; mac_adr=${quux} 
sudo hdiutil create -size ${s}b -fs JHFS+X -volname "${n}" -type SPARSEBUNDLE \
"/Volumes/${mp}/${cn}_${mac_addr}.sparsebundle" && echo "Done"
```

does not work, but

```
declare -i s=${foo}; n=${bar}; mp=${baz}; cn=${qux}; mac_adr=${quux} 
sudo hdiutil create -size ${s}b -fs JHFS+X -volname "${n}" -type SPARSEBUNDLE \
"/Volumes/${cn}_${mac_addr}.sparsebundle" &&
sudo mv -vn "/Volumes/${cn}_${mac_addr}.sparsebundle" "/Volumes/${mp}" && echo "Done"
```

Works correctly

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's the other way round - at least in Sierra: the first one works and the second one doesn't

Comment: @klanomath OS X 10.9.5

Comment: [link]("https://monosnap.com/file/e8oT3Fr9c7KCUrROKOukIS7bcIyIKw.png")[link] ("https://monosnap.com/file/bOe9UmJZmaR8Z2j0Ez7d2R5MFvUnaZ.png")

Comment: The volume with the name Data has to exist of course - that was just an example...

Comment: [link]http://take.ms/hJEna [link]http://take.ms/JfpIW

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So (without sudo before hdiutil) it works:

```
clear; read -p "Желаемый размер раздела в GB? = " s; ((s= 10**9*s/512)); read -p "Введите название раздела? = " n; cn=`scutil --get ComputerName`; mac_addr=`ifconfig en0 | grep "ether"`; mac_addr=${mac_addr#*ether}; mac_addr=${mac_addr// /}; mac_addr=${mac_addr//:/}; read -p "Точка Монтирования = " mp; hdiutil create -size ${s}b -fs JHFS+X -volname "${n}" -type SPARSEBUNDLE "/Volumes/${mp}/${cn}_${mac_addr}.sparsebundle" && echo "Done"

Желаемый размер раздела в GB? = 10
Введите название раздела? = rrr
Точка Монтирования = Data
created: /Volumes/Data/Air_60c54700b918.sparsebundle
Done
```

The matter of rights on the network drive:

```
hdiutil - verbose
DIDiskImageCreateWithCFURL: creator returned 0  
::getBandEntry: chown() - 501  
Сompletion...  

DIHLDiskImageCreate() returned 1    
hdiutil: create: returning 1  
hdiutil: create failed - operation is not permitted
this file is created, but then the operation fails, before he makes the format:  
DIDiskImageCreateWithCFURL: creator returned 0  
DI_kextWaitQuiet: about to call IOServiceWaitQuiet...  
DI_kextWaitQuiet: IOServiceWaitQuiet took 0.000011 seconds  
Formatting ...
Completing ...
created: /Volumes/Data/Air_60c22700b922.sparsebundle
```

Do not use "sudo" to the shared network resources!

Comment: Don't steel my answer! You should accept my answer instead of repeating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following command in 10.9.5:

```
read -p "Size in GB? = " s; ((s= 10**9*s/512)); read -p "Name of image volume? = " n; read -p "External Volume name (Escape spaces with a backslash - the volume has to exist)? = " m; cn=`scutil --get ComputerName`; mac_addr=`ifconfig en0 | grep "ether"`; mac_addr=${mac_addr#*ether}; mac_addr=${mac_addr// /} ; mac_addr=${mac_addr//:/}; sudo hdiutil create -size ${s}b -fs JHFS+X -volname "${n}" -type SPARSEBUNDLE "/Volumes/${m}/${cn}_${mac_addr}.sparsebundle" && echo "Done"
```

and it works (with a workaround for spaces in volume names like "Macintosh HD") for internal volumes:

```
Size in GB? = 2
Name of image volume? = aaa
Existing External Volume Name (Escape spaces with a backslash)? = test\ 2
created: /Volumes/test 2/host_001122334455.sparsebundle
Done
host:~ user$
```

This doesn't work if you create a sparsebundle on a network share. Here you mustn't use the `sudo` command. Instead use (I also simplified $mac_addr):

```
read -p "Size in GB? = " s; ((s= 10**9*s/512)); read -p "Name of image volume? = " n; read -p "External Volume name (Escape spaces with a backslash - the volume has to exist)? = " m; cn=`scutil --get ComputerName`; mac_addr=`ifconfig en0 | grep ether | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/://g'`; hdiutil create -size ${s}b -fs JHFS+X -volname "${n}" -type SPARSEBUNDLE "/Volumes/${m}/${cn}_${mac_addr}.sparsebundle" && echo "Done"
```

Comment: Please see the answer below:

Comment: @cave-canem Updated answer

Comment: There is no need to use the "awk" From minimalist prntsipe if "bash" built-in tools can be used.
"Sudo" should not be used with a network share, see "hdiutil -verbose"

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I can see is that you are trying to create sparse bundle on different volumes. /Volume/test.sparsebundle will be located on your startup disk. /Volume/Data/test.sparsebundle will be located (probably) on another disk. Please try to check what kind of filesystem is on your second drive.

You can try your issue both commands with -debug option and compare result.

Comment: /Volume/Data/test.sparsebundle Is sparsebundle on Time Capsule

Comment: Have you tried the same with `-debug` option?